# Reopen request for "Tell colleagues about booster shot"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Tell colleagues about booster shot](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181974/tell-colleagues-about-booster-shot)

I really don't understand why people, including mods, are so trigger happy to close questions with the reason:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals.

This question is **CLEARLY NOT** asking about company-specific regulations, agreements, policies, or asking about legal advice.

The content of the question is (emphasis mine):

> Is it proper **etiquette** to inform your work colleagues that you are getting a covid booster shot in the future and you may be put of commission on that day?
>
> Or should you keep it to yourself?

So the question has nothing to do with workplace rules. In fact, the OP has carefully ensured that it shouldn't be interpreted that way. They explicitly said "etiquette".

An answer may suggest: "You should keep in mind that there may be workplace policies that require you to disclose." The potential existence of a policy covering such a thing doesn't mean we should close the question.

Comment: I must say this wasn't trigger happy. We even chatted on the mod's chat live on that post and monitored it closely (comments were derailing considerably)... anyways I think it *does* depend on several reason, many of them location-dependent or company-specific. Etiquette is dependent on aspects like those IMHO.

Comment: @DarkCygnus We have people from all around the world. If the question needs some locale information, that should be asked for in a comment, rather than the question being closed. I was giving the mods the benefit of the doubt, but if there was a collective decision then a collective wrong one was made.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Just like you clearly disagree, somewhat bitterly, with the closure of the question, I disagree with your take on why we closed it and whether that was a "unilateral" action. I've clarified the reason for the closure in my comment, two other mods have provided additional clarification here but you seem intent on disregarding that input. As mentioned in my comment it would be great to have a higher quality question on the general topic so feel free to post one. But this particular question was problematic for multiple reasons.

Comment: @Lilienthal I haven't disregarded anything. You collectively have made an error, and presumably are too proud to admit as such. None of you have actually justified the decision at all.

Comment: I think it's a case where the user was banned, and now you want to punish them further by closing the question. You guys couldn't find a suitable reason, so are just pretending the question is asking about workplace policy in the hope that other users are too stupid to notice.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I strongly disagree but it seems like we'll have to leave it at that. At this point we've provided plenty of reasons for why we took the actions we did but if you refuse to accept those there's not much else I can do. Rest assured that we are not in the habit of "punishing users" for anything. If you have any further concerns I can only direct you to the Community Team via the contact page.

Comment: @Lilienthal ... No reasons have been provided. DarkCygnus has said it's a locale specific, which isn't a reason. They also suggest it's company specific, in which case they could write an answer on how the OP should proceed to determine how to find out. Motosubatsu didn't provide any justification on why it was closed at all.

Answer (score 7):

I'm really not convinced this closure can really be classed as "trigger happy" - it wasn't just the mods taking unilateral action as at the time of closure it had already attracted two other close-votes from the community.

I wasn't involved in the chat discussion DarkCygnus mentioned as I'd already left both the actual and metaphorical office for the day, but I've read back over it this morning and I wouldn't have objected to the closure had I been there.

From my own point of view I really don't see what there is to gain were it to be re-opened, the OP account had been removed prior to the closure (for moderation reasons unrelated to the question) and therefore isn't coming back to clarify anything or accept an answer, and the 7 answers that are already there cover the subject fairly exhaustively and a couple of the comment threads were getting out of hand.

Comment: Well, I would say it's clearly trigger-happy because there was actually no need for unilateral action.

Comment: The most obvious gain to reopening the question would be to undo a mistake. That, in itself, is a worthy goal. Moderators shouldn't be trying to curate content by using unrelated close reasons, and then ducking behind the "what is to be gained" question after the fact. It's not up to me to answer that. The status quo is content should be unmolested by moderators and only touched with good reason. It doesn't fall on the wider community to justify to moderators why content should be allowed. How about you justify HOW it matches the close reason given.

Comment: And if you want a clear specific reason why it should be opened: other people may have that exact same query. It's not some strange corner-case. It's a thing that many people will face.

Comment: I wouldn't have objected either, the question is impossible in my region so makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Kilisi I would have thought your assessment would be based on the merits of the question, not if you were personally able to answer or not. Criteria is getting really hard to understand around here.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie sure, but if something makes no sense to me I won't make a judgement in either direction. My assessment was that it was out of my experience.

Comment: Fact: the closure of the question was about 23 hours after the posting of it. This make it evident this wasn't "trigger-happy".